# is there an app to filter out or identify ad-ware in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

There is no content filter that would let me filter out Adware from the Play Store app listing, and apparently apps that display ads can identify themselves as "Free", and there's no "Adware" app-type.

Is there a 3rd-party app that will help me identify whether a particular app is ad-ware, or better yet, hook into the PlayStore listing and exclude such apps?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: A hint, though: See my list on [Ad-Modules and Privacy Checker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules)

Answer (score 0):

In the past couple years of building roms, I have never come across an application that can detect adware from the playstore **pre** install.  There are plenty of applications that will detect it on your device such as pretty much any antivirus software.

My advice would be to just make sure your phone/tablet/whatever is protected with a good antivirus such as Avast the same way one would protect their computer from the same threats.